# Geometry filtering in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, cql-filter

Is there anything like OpenLayers.Filter implemented yet in Openlayers 3? I'm trying to implement a DWITHIN filter using a ol.geom.Polygon and I am searching for API support, which I couldn't find.

Comment: There is no filter framework in ol3. Do you want this to build a CQL filter, or do you want to filter features of a vector source client side?

Comment: I want to build a cql filter. I've built it manuaually for now by taking the flatCoordinates from Geometry. There are no getters for the coordinates. I wonder why's that...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to build the CQL filter manually, but `ol.format.WKT` can help you to get the polygon coordinates in the correct WKT format. So in the end you'll be writing something like

```
var format = new ol.format.WKT();
var filter = 'DWITHIN (SHAPE, ' +
    format.writeGeometry(feature.getGeometry()) +
    ', 10, kilometers)';
```